# Parent node receives unwanted mouseout from child nodes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="scrollable">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
</div>
```

I'm attaching event handlers to the `#scrollable` div - `mouseover`, `mousedown`, `mouseup` in order to implement a scrolling effect with the mouse dragging the div. The problem is that I get `mouseout` for the `#scrollable` div whenever the mouse moves between the two divs while remaining inside the div.
So the mouse is inside the `@scrollable` div but just move from item1 to item2 - and this breaks my dragging.

Is there a way to circumvent this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are not handling these events in the inner divs, so they bubble up to the parent.  One way would be to add an event handler to the children and suppress that event so that this doesn't happen.

Regards

Comment: i tried that. i stopped the bubbling in the inner divs for the mouse out event. but then the problem was that i didn't got the mouseout for the main div when the mouse actually got out of it...